# Clamping always returns 0

Tags: unity, c#

I have a class with three fields:

- `StartingAngleOnRotationPlane` is 180
- `MinimumRotatedAngleX` is 0
- `MaximumRotatedAngleX` is 140

Here is the offending code:

```
public virtual float ClampRotatedDegreesWithinAllowedRange()
{
    float rotatedAngle = this.transform.GetRotatedAngleOnXPlane();
    Debug.Log("Rotated " + rotatedAngle);

    float clampedRotatedAngle =
        Mathf.Clamp(
            AngleNormaliser.BetweenNegativeAndPositive180(this.StartingAngleOnRotationPlane + rotatedAngle),
            this.MinimumRotatedAngleX,
            this.MaximumRotatedAngleX);

    return clampedRotatedAngle;
}
```

Here is the debug window:

[image]

As you can see, when the breakpoint was hit, `rotatedAngle` was -178.9446.

To calculate `clampedRotatedAngle`, `rotatedAngle` is added to `StartingAngleOnRotationPlane`, supplied to a method called `AngleNormaliser.BetweenNegativeAndPositive180(float input)`, and then clamped between `MinimumRotatedAngleX` (0) and `MaximumRotatedAngleX` (140).

Here is the code for `AngleNormaliser.BetweenNegativeAndPositive180(float input)`:

```
public static float BetweenNegativeAndPositive180(float angleBetween0And360)
{
    while (angleBetween0And360 > 180)
    {
        angleBetween0And360 -= 360;
    }

    while (angleBetween0And360 < -180)
    {
        angleBetween0And360 += 360;
    }

    return angleBetween0And360;
}
```

Here is the debug window when `AngleNormaliser.BetweenNegativeAndPositive180(float input)` was invoked:

[image]

By the time the `return` statement was hit, the result 1.055389 should be returned and assigned to the variable `clampedRotatedAngle`, since 1.055389 is within the clamping range (0 - 140).

However, that was not the case:

[image]

As you can see, `clampedRotatedAngle` was still zero.

In fact, `clampedRotatedAngle` is always zero, regardless of what I feed into the `Mathf.Clamp` function:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please post your code as text, not as screenshots.

Comment: @Galandil Done :-)

Comment: are you sure `MinimumRotatedAngleX` is 0?

Comment: @Bálint Yes. I will take another debugger screenshot with that value included.

Comment: Also, what'a `StartingAngleOnRotationPlane`?

Comment: @Bálint It is a float.

Comment: FYI converting to and from angles is not the best way to go about things. Instead use trigonometric identities to do your math as much as possible.

Comment: @DMGregory he's right though, since `angleBetween0And360` is 1.055389, and the boundaries of `Clamp` are 0-140, the latter should return 1.055389 and not 0. Unless there's something wrong not shown here due to the use of `this` and from where he calls the methods.

Comment: Apologies, I'm on mobile and misread the method when scrolling horizontally. I notice that -178.9446 is very close to -180 + 1.055. Are you certain that at runtime, this.StartingAngleOnRotationPlane is +180 and not -180?

Comment: To verify that clamping is actually the problem, dump the min & max values to output immediately before calling clamp.

Answer (score 2):

```
StartingAngleOnRotationPlane is 180
MinimumRotatedAngleX is 0
MaximumRotatedAngleX is 140
```

Are these variables public or serialized? In that case Unity might be taking the values set from editor. In this case I think your MaximumRotatedAngleX is set to 0.